# A question about elements of sets

Tags: logic, set-theory

If $x$ is a set and $y\in x$, will it imply $y$ is a set?

Can we prove it using just axioms of Set theory and formal proof system?

If we add this as axiom in Axiom of Set theory, will new axiom system be inconsistent because of Lowernheim Skolem theory? (as there will not any countable model of such axiom system then)

Where by proving element of set is set, I mean to prove $(\forall x)(\forall y)((\exists z)(z=x)\longrightarrow(\exists l)(l=y))$

Comment: In usual axiomatic set theory, like $\mathsf {ZF}$, every "object" is a *set*.

Comment: Usually, the axiom of well-foundedness (at least in the presence of all the other axioms of ZF) is taken to imply that every object is a set whose elements are sets whose elements... And so on, until you finally reach the empty set, always, after a finite number of "steps".

Comment: Some set theories have so called _urelements_, objects which aren't sets. Others have only sets (so the most 'basic' set is the empty set).

Comment: we take so. But can axioms of ZF prove this: $(\forall x)(\forall y)((\exists z)(z=x)\longrightarrow(\exists l)(l=y))$

Comment: axioms of ZF given in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo–Fraenkel_set_theory

Comment: @Sushil "$(\forall y)(\exists l)(l=y)$" is a tautology (= provable from no axioms at all) - just take $l=y$. ZF doesn't have a distinction between "things" and "sets" - **everything** is a set in ZF. Maybe a clearer way of saying this is: there is no specific word/idea "set" in ZF, all objects are treated the same way.

Comment: I don't understand what your last statement is supposed to say.

Comment: See second para of your Wiki's link: "ZFC is intended to formalize a single primitive notion, that of a hereditary well-founded set, so that all entities in the universe of discourse are such sets. Thus the axioms of ZFC refer only to pure sets and prevent its models from containing urelements (elements of sets that are not themselves sets). "

Comment: In second statement I was refering that if ZF is consistent, it has to have a countable model. So in that model,  power set of natural number will be countable. Right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the language of ZF includes a special **sort** for "sets" - so that there is a distinction between "set variables" and "general variables." This is a feature of some set theories with urelements, but not of ZF: there is only one kind of "object" (syntactically speaking, only one kind of variable) in ZF.

This means that a formula like "$(\forall x)(\exists z)(x=z)$" is a tautology (= provable from no axioms at all) - just take $x=z$. **If we had a language with sorts**, then things would be more interesting: the sentence $$(\forall x^\sigma)(\exists z^\tau )(x=z),$$ asserting that every thing of type $\sigma$ is also a thing of type $\tau$, is definitely not a tautology. *(Actually, the opposite may be true: most presentations of many-sorted logic demand that the sorts be distinct! But that's a minor point here.)*

Comment: So in minimal countable model of ZF(assuming consistency of ZF which exists), Power set of natural number will bw countable. Right?

Comment: as we will have power set of natural number in that set but as elements are from that set only. It has to be countable.

Comment: @Sushil It will be *externally* countable, but *internally* uncountable. That is, suppose $M$ is a countable model of ZF, and let $a$ be the element of $M$ which $M$ thinks is the powerset of the set of natural numbers - usually denoted by "$(\mathcal{P}(\omega))^M$." Then $a$ is countable in reality, even though $M$ thinks that $a$ is uncountable. (Incidentally there is no need for minimality of the model here, only countability.)

Comment: The key to understanding this is to note that when we say "$M$ thinks $a$ is uncountable," what we mean is "there is no injection in $M$ from $a$ to $\omega$." But just because no such injection exists *inside $M$* doesn't mean no such injection exists *in reality*. This is sometimes referred to as [Skolem's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox), and is a subtle weakness (or feature, depending who you ask) of first-order logic.

Comment: (I'm being slightly sloppy in my comments above - e.g. one should distinguish between the *element* $a\in M$ and the *external set* $\{b\in M: M\models b\in a\}$. If you'd like an absolutely precise description of the situation, I can write that too, but I think it would be more confusing than helpful at this stage.)

Comment: no I think it is clearing things more. Can you please write on it, I may ask another ask for it?

Comment: @Sushil Alright, here's the in-depth version. Suppose I have a model $M$ of ZF. Each element $e\in M$ has a corresponding set - in the real word - $\{b\in M: b\in^M e\}$; I'll denote this by "$[e]_M$." Intuitively we conflate $e$ and $[e]_M$, but technically they're different things. For example, maybe $M$ happens to have underlying set $\mathbb{N}$ (totally possible!); then each element of $M$ is a natural number, but $[e]_M$ will be a set of natural numbers (for $e\in M$). (cont'd)

Comment: OK, now suppose $M$ is a countable model of ZF. ZF proves (expressed appropriately) "the powerset of $\omega$ exists;" let $a\in M$ be such that $M\models$"$a$" is the powerset of $\omega$." Externally to $M$ - that is, in the "real world" - there is a bijection $b$ between $[a]_M$ and $[\omega^M]_M$, since each is infinite and (since $M$ is countable) countable. So that's the *external* picture. The point is, though, that this bijection $b$ has no reason to be an element of, or rather *correspond to* an element of, $M$; this is the *internal* picture. (cont'd)

Comment: What do I mean? Well, suppose $c\in M$ is such that $M\models$"$c$ is a function from $a$ to $\omega^M$." The element $c$ induces a function $f_c$ in the real world from $[a]_M$ to $[\omega^M]_M$, given by $f_c(x)=y$ iff $M\models (x, y)\in c$. (Working through the details here is a good exercise.) Then "$M$ thinks $a$ is uncountable" means exactly "there is no $c\in M$ such that $f_c$ is a bijection between $[a]_M$ and $[\omega^M]_M$."

Comment: Thanks that's why I got now why Skelom said that 'Thus it is possible to recognise that a particular set u is countable, but not countable in a particular model of set theory, because there is no set in the model that gives a one-to-one correspondence between u and the natural numbers in that model.'

Comment: Just one thing, wouldn't $[\omega^M]_M$ be just $\omega$. Because every natural number will be in this model, right?

Comment: provinf $f_c$ is function is not difficult right. Because $f_c$ will be just set consisting of these ordered pair. We need to prove $(x, y_1) \land(x, y_2) \in f_c$, then   $ y_1=y_2$. Now $(x, y_1) \land(x, y_2) \in f_c$ by definition means $(x, y_1) \land (x, y_2) \in c$ which implies $y_1=_M y_2$. But equality is absolute, hence $y_1=y_2$ in real world also

Comment: @Sushil Every natural number will be in the model but the model might have things it thinks are natural numbers but are actually infinite. This is exactly the same situation that we have with [**nonstandard models of arithmetic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic). Of course, if we assume e.g. that $M$ is transitive, then this won't happen. (Incidentally, even if $M$ is transitive "$[\omega^M]_M=\omega$" won't be exactly right - again, the elements of $M$ could be anything. Rather, what will be true is that $(\omega^M,\in^M)$ and $(\omega,\in)$ will be isomorphic.

Comment: It's worth noting that nonstandard arithmetic arises from compactness, which is essentially the opposite of Lowenheim-Skolem; basically, these are two different senses in which a model of set theory can be "wrong" (they aren't the only ones btw).

Comment: Thanks. And is my proof right?

Comment: @Sushil Looks right to me!